# JSP, find missing ids in elements

Tags: html, jsp

I have been given a task to go through all the JSPs of the application and find the elements which dont have ids in them. 
    For example -

```
 <input type="text" name="BANANA" value="banana"/>
```

Is there any validation tool that can help me find such elements?

Comment: I think you can try with unix (i.e. grep ) if your familiar with it.

Comment: Writing a script for such a task would be very tedious. My JPS contains entries like <td> , <c:forEach>, <c:if> etc etc.

Comment: Found it - I am going to use something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758046/regex-for-finding-elements-without-a-certain-attribute-e-g-id

Answer (score -1):

With Jquery you might use $(":not([id])") , this returns every element(also hmtl,body etc..) but not elements with id attribute